# Suppose a pizza has 4 slices, and each slice can be topped with either peppers, onions, or both. How many different pizzas can be made?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-groups, word-problem

> Suppose a pizza has 4 slices, and each slice can be topped with either peppers, onions, or both. How many different pizzas can be made?

I am using Burnside's counting theorem with the group $G=\left \{(1),r,r^{2},r^{3}  \right \}$ acting on the set $\left \{P,O,B  \right \}$. I understand why $|X_{(1)}|=81$ and $|X_{r}|=|X_{r^{3}}|=3$, but why does $|X_{r^{2}}|=9$?

I drew a diagram:

[image]

Wouldn't it still be $3$ options since none of the slices are the same as the original after two rotations?

Comment: How do you define a unique pizza? It seems clear that symmetries of pizzas shouldn't count as different pizzas but If I have a plain pizza with mushrooms on one slice and peppers on another, does is matter whether or not the two slices with the toppings are adjacent to each other?

Comment: Suppose I am looking down at two pizzas.  A has peppers on one slice and onions on the next slice clockwise.  B has the onions counterclockwise from the peppers, thus the mirror image of A.  Same or different?

Comment: Hmmm, For $r^2$ then slices $1$ and $3$ must be equal and the slices $2$ $4$ must be equal.  There are $3$ options that slice$1$ can be and $3$ options slice $2$ can be.  So that's $3^2=9$ options.

Comment: "How do you define a unique pizza?" It's clear in the op unique up to rotation but not symmetry.  "Same or different?"  Different.

Comment: "Wouldn't it still be 3 options since none of the slices are the same as the original after two rotations?" No.  After one rotation you have $1\to 2;2\to 3; 3\to 4;4\to 1$ so for this to be the *SAME* pizza we need $1=2=3=4$ and there are $3$ ways to do that. (All peppers, all onions, or all both).  After two rotations you have $1\to3;2\to 4;3\to1;4\to 2$ so for this to be the same pizza we need $1=3; 2=4$ and there are $3*3=9$ was to do this.  $1$ and $3$ are one of three toppings, and $2$ and $4$ are one of three toppings.

Comment: In other words the ones that get shifted must be the same as the ones they get shifted to.  For no rotation, none get shifted to any others, so there are four independent choices and $3^4$ option.  For a single turn everyone gets shifted to the one to the right and so everyone is dependant on each other.  There is *one* chain *one* choice so $3^1$ options. For a double turn each gets shifted to its opposite but are independent of the the others.  So there are two independent pairs or $3^2$ options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3^4$ ways to top the four slices.  $|X_g|$ are the number of those ways that will still be the same four slices in the same position after we rotate the pizza rotation $g$.

Let the original slices of the pizza be $a,b,c,d$ and $g_a, g_b, g_c, g_d$.  be slices after rotation.

For $1$ (don't rotate the pizza) we have $1_a = a; 1_b=b; 1_c =c; 1_d = d$.

The $X_1$ are the pizzas that don't change when we don't do anything.  ... Well, that's every one of the $81$ pizzas.  Or to be thorough.  $X_1$ are the pizzas where $1_a = a = a; 1_b=b=b; 1_c=c=c$ and $1_d =d=d$. And $1_a = a = a$ can be any of the $3$ options and ... so on.

Fr $r$ (rotate the pizza $90^\circ$) we have $r_a = d; r_b=a; r_c=d; r_d = a$.  (Because the slice *now* in the $a$ slot was origianlly in the $d$ slot and so on.  If your intuition is the exact opposite and you think $r_a$ should equal $b$ because the original $a$ slice is now in the $b$ slot... when that works too; we just have to be consistant.  For me, is seems to me $g_k$ means "the slice that is now in the $k$ spot was originally in what slot".)

So For the $X_r$ are the pizzas in which $r_a = d=  a; r_b= a = b; r_c = b=c; r_d = a = d$.  (In other words the ones where slice $a$ once rotated to position $b$ still has the same topping that the original slice in position $b$ had.)  This means $a = b = c =d$.  I.e.all the slices are the same.  And $|X_r| = 3$ because there are $3$ options that this topping can be.

And $r^2$ (rotating $180^\circ$) means $r^2_a = c; r^2_b = d; r^2_c = a; r^2_d = b$.  So $X_{r^2}$ are the pizzas where $r^2_a = c = a; r^2_b = d = b; r^2_c = a= c; $ and $r^2_d=a = d$.  Or in other words where $c=a; b=d$.  Slice $a = c$ can be anly of $3$ options as can $b=d$.  So $|X_{r^2}| = 3^2 = 9$.

Similarly $r^3$ (rotating $270^{\circ}$) mean $r^3_a = b; r^3_b=c; r^3_c = d; r^3_d =a$ and $X_{r^3}$ are where $r^3_a = b =a; r^3_b=c=b;r^3_c=d=c; r^3_d =a =d$ or $a=b=c=d$ and $|X_{r^3}| = 3$.

So by Burnside's Counting Theorem there are:

$\frac 1{|G|}(|X_1| + |X_r| + |X_{r^2}| + |X_{r^3}| ) =\frac 14(81 + 3+ 9 + 3) = 24$.

Which.. seemms to work:

All the same: 1111, 22222, 3333,(three choices for the 1, one way to arrange it.)

Three of one, one of another: 1222,1333,2111,2333,3111,3222 (three choices for three slices, two for the remaining one)

Two of one, two of another: 1122,1212,1133,1313,2233,2323 (three pairs, two ways to arrange)

Two of one, one of each of the others: 1123,1132,1213, 2213,2231, 2123, 3312, 3321, 3132 (Three choices for the two slices, three ways to arrange them)

Answer (score 1):

Denote peppers by $1$, onions by $2$ and both by $3$.

Since there are $3$ different choices for each slice, there are $3$ ways to make a pizza with every slice the same.

Suppose $3$ of the slices are the same. Then there are $2$ choices for the fourth slice so there are $3\cdot 2=6$ ways to make a pizza with $3$ slices the same.

Suppose $2$ of the slices are the same. Note that there are only $3$ choices for each of $4$ slices so at least two of the slices must be the same.

There are $3$ ways to make two of the slices the same and the remaining two slices can be either the same or different. Given a topping for the two slices that are the same, there is only one way to make the remaining two slices different for a total of $3$ ways. For each topping on the first two slices, there are $2$ ways to make the other two slices the same for a total of $6$ ways to get pairs of slices with identical toppings. But each of these gets counted twice, e.g. $(1122)$ and $(2211)$, so there are only $3$ ways to create pairs of identical slices for a total of $6$ ways to have two identical slices.

Therefore, we can make $3+6+6=15$ different pizzas.

Comment: This assumes that 1212 is the same as 1122.  I think the OP made it clear pizzas are only the same if they can be rotated to coincide.  As 1212 = 2121 but 1122 $\ne$ 1212 and 1231 = 1123 $ne$ 1132$ nor does it equal 1213.

Comment: @fleablood I wondered about that. I even asked. I assumed two pizzas were isomorphic if they both satisfy the same set of consumers. So, for your $1213$ example, two slices are peppers, one is is onions and one is both. Any permutation satisfies the owners of the individual slices. I will delete this answer if the OP chimes in and clarifies. If these were circles whose quarter sectors were painted different colors then we would be in perfect agreement that $1123\ne 1213$.

Comment: I'm basing my assumptions *entirely* upon that the OP is attempting to use Burnside theorem. One has to admit that in practicality people will care how many slices of what we have but no-one will really care how the slices are arranged.  On the other extreme we could say there is a NORTH, EAST, WEST, SOUTH slice and three options for each so there are $81$ pizzas. Which means rotating a pizza makes it a different pizza.

Comment: @fleablood I understand your point and have a practical example. Suppose a kid wins his first go-cart race and his parents want to get him a pizza that looks like a checkered flag. They do this by ordering a pizza with mushrooms in the upper left and lower right sectors and plain, otherwise. They would not be happy if a half plain and half mushroom pizza was delivered.

Comment: ... But what if it were delivered sideways?!  That instead of the mushrooms in the upper left and lower right corners, the mushrooms were in the upper right and lower left corners!  Or the pizza was twisted sideways so the mushrooms were on the top and bottom!  Or the left and right!

Comment: @fleablood These are all good points. If the mushrooms were in the upper  right and lower left instead of the upper left and lower right then we would just have to sit on a different side of the pizza.The same is true of the adjacent same-slice case. It is clear that rotations of the pizza yield the same pizza. The question boils down to your earlier point: is $1123=1213$? The reason I am not using the OP's attempt as an implicit clarification of the rules is that the question makes no such distinctions.  The poster may be making assumptions about the problem that aren't correct.

Comment: Which is why I'm taking the OP at his/her word that s/he wishes to use Burnside theorem.  In which case rotation is reasonably enough to assume the pizzas are the same.  However Oscar Lanzi's comment that symmettry might also be enough.  In which case we can use Burnside with $G = <1,r,r^2, r^3, s, sr, sr^2,sr^3>$ where $s = 2\to 4; 4\to 2$.  $|X_s|=27;|X_{sr}|=3;|X_{sr^2}|=27;|X_{sr^3}|=3$ so number of ways is $\frac 18 (81+3+9+3+27+3+27+3)=19.5$ ...okay I made an arithmetical error somewhere...

Comment: ... okay, $|X_{sr}|=|X_{sr^3}|=9\ne 3$ so $21$ pizzas.

Comment: @fleablood I get $21$ if $1123=1132$ define equivalent pizzas and $24$ otherwise.

Comment: Right if $1234 = 2341 = 3412=4123$ then there are $\frac 14(27+3+9+3)=24$ pizzas.  If $1234=2341=3412=4123=1432=4321=3214=2143$ then there are $\frac 18(27+3+9+3+27+9+27+9)=21$. If we went further to allow 1234=1243 or any combos we get well... we should get $\frac 1{24}{360}=15$ but I'm finding Burnside to be kind of tedious to calculate.